# wait for Cypress each() function to finish

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, each, cypress

I am calling a function `populateArray` which picks elements on the page using `children()` function. I want to store the attribute values into an using `each()` function.
Here is what I am doing

```
static populateArray(){
let arr = []

 cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL).children(NODE_TYPE)
                 .each((element, index, list) => arr.push(cy.wrap(element).invoke('attr', 'data-testid')))
}
```

The problem is when I call this function by assigning it to a variable

`actualArray = ArticlePage.populateArray()`

its not waiting for underlying each() function to complete fully. It just pick partial values and proceeds. I want `actualArray` to have values only after `populateArray` is fully resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `Cypress.Promise`? From the docs

> Cypress is promise aware so if you return a promise from inside of commands like .then(), Cypress ***will not continue until those promises resolve***

```
const populateArray = () => {
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let arr = []
    cy.xpath('//ul')
      .children('li')
      .each(element => arr.push(element.attr('data-testid'))) // NOTE different push
      .then(() => {
        return resolve(arr)
      })
  })
}
```

Call with await (test must be async),

```
it('gets the array', async () => {

  const actualArray = await ArticlePage.populateArray();
  expect(actualArray).to.deep.equal(['1', '2', '3']);  // whatever is in 'data-testid'

})
```

Comment: So I am calling ```actualArray = await ArticlePage.populateArray()``` from a different js file. How can I await for this specific Promise to resolve in that case? @eric99

Comment: I had the Promise in the wrong place, so corrected that and it now works as I originally expected! (Shock - a tester is actually testing)

Comment: My assumption is you would use the result in a test, but if another function gets the result then it must be declared `async` for `await` to work.

Comment: I think @RosenMihaylov shows a better pattern, I'll test it out now.

Comment: I find it doesn't make a lot of difference - if you don't use a promise, you get back a "chainer" which means you have to use `.then()` in the test to get the actual array. Which way is preferred depends on how you want to use the result (inside an `it()` or inside another function).

Answer (score 3):

Since `.each()` can be chained - you can chain a [.then](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html) and just type the code you need to execute after the `.each()` process is done:

```
static populateArray(){
    let arr = []

    cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL).children(NODE_TYPE)
        .each((element, index, list) => arr.push(arr.push(element.attr('data-testid')))
            .then(list => {
                cy.wrap(arr).as('actualArray')
            })
}
```

And in test code

```
populateArray()
cy.get('@actualArray')
    .then(actualArray => {
        //code that needs the array data
    })
```

Comment: Actually, I think you're almost right - except that `cy.wrap()` returns a chainer, and @Boon wants just the array, so return the unwrapped array?

Comment: I had tried to return something that can be used as a constant, but never successfully, so for that point I suppose returning a promise can help. I still prefer chaining that has proven it`s value to me or assigning an alias

Comment: What about if there's a return before `cy.xpath()`? I was about to test the variations, but my feeling after seeing your answer is that returning a Promise is overkill.

Comment: May be it will work. Any way I think if you need a variable - just assign an allias at the place of returning the cy.wrap()

Comment: So I just tried both ways, returning Promise and returning cy.wrap(), but in both cases getting an error `Unhandled rejection CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code`.

Comment: Did you try assigning an allias?

Comment: Same thing - the Cypress log shows red on `.each()`, and browser console shows the error, so I don't think it's getting to the `.then()`

Comment: Thanks @RosenMihaylov and @eric99. 
I tried Promises , but I always got  ```mixing up async and sync code``` error. 
It's 2 days of me banging my head against the wall

Comment: What do you need to return as an variable?

Comment: @Boon - yeah we just found that out too. Even if you move the `cy.xpath().each()` out of the static class and call it in the test, same thing happens. I would not expect it, but will hack about a bit more.

Comment: I thought of a sollution with a custom command give me a few minutes.

Comment: Instead of `arr.push(cy.wrap(element).invoke('attr', 'data-testid'))` we need `arr.push(element.attr('data-testid'))`

Answer (score 0):

Another answer using [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#History)

```
Cypress.Commands.add("populateArray", (parentSelector, childSelector, arrayAllias) => {
    let arr = []

    cy.xpath(parentSelector).children(childSelector)
        .each((element, index, list) => arr.push(element.attr('data-testid')))
        .then(()=>{
            cy.wrap(arr).as(arrayAllias)
        })
})
```

And in test code

```
cy.populateArray(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL, NODE_TYPE, 'actualArray')
cy.get('@actualArray')
    .then(actualArray => {
        //code that needs the array data
    })
```

Comment: Also don't do `arr.push(cy.wrap(element).invoke('attr', 'data-testid'))`, do `arr.push(element.attr('data-testid'))` - the first one gives a Cypress error.

Comment: I adjusted this suggestion of mine according to your feedback.

Comment: @eric99 and Rosen - thanks a lot both of you . This solution worked for me. 
What a relief after 2 days :) . thanks again

Comment: Boon would You put a mark that this is the working solution so people reading can know ?